# Composer does not find match for deeper dev-dependency

Tags: git, composer-php, repository

I have a Symfony App, which requires a Bundle from a private repository:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "ssh://git@XX/apm-library.git" },
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "ssh://git@XX/apm-bundle.git" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "apm-bundle": "dev-some-branch-name#354d4c6c49b1e97c81b589d8ae72301dbd99949c"
    }
}
```

The Bundle requires a Library from a private repository:

```
{
    "name": "apm-bundle",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "ssh://git@XX/apm-library.git" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "apm-library": "dev-some-branch-name#12b79acef80795e5a70632867d40b82f574a5fdc"
    }
}
```

I am developing App and Library simultaneously, so what I did is (as seen above):

1. requested branch-version of the Bundle
2. where this Bundle branch requests branch-version of the Library

When I try to install/update Bundle in the App, I'm having this problem:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for apm-bundle dev-some-branch-name#354d4c6c49b1e97c81b589d8ae72301dbd99949c -> satisfiable by apm-bundle[dev-some-branch-name].
- apm-bundle dev-some-branch-name requires apm-library dev-some-branch-name#12b79acef80795e5a70632867d40b82f574a5fdc -> no matching package found.
```

**no matching package found**

Seems like it does not look up for the "dev" branches this deep.

When I do composer update in Bundle itself - it successfully resolves such version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've messed up something with your example - `apm-bundle` requires itself and `apm-library` is never required. Is there any chance you can share real `composer.json` files without modifications?

Comment: And why you're using hashes as constraints in the first place?

Comment: @rob006, thanks for pointing out the typo. I've fixed it.
1. I cannot share entire composer.json, but I believe I've shared enought. There's no additional configuration parameters in them. Just required components,
2. I'm using hashes to work with certain commits/repository states. I believe this can't be an issue as it hais a valid syntax.

Comment: Using hashes in constraint is more like a hack and has some limitations - I suggest to try remove them and rely on `composer.lock` to lock dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `minimum-stability: "dev"` to your `composer.json` should help. By default, Composer does not install non stable transient dependencies, you need to enable those with the said config.